# JSON and XML threat protection in WSO2 API Manager is not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

When I was trying "JSON/XML Threat Protection for API Gateway" in WSO2 APIM 3.1.0, by adding a mediation policy. It isn't considering the custom policy that I've written, it's taking the default values which are 100.

Anything more I should be adding, please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

Once a new mediation sequence is implemented, it needs to be upload and select as a mediation sequence in the "Message Mediation" section. Once selected need to republish to apply the changes.
You can confirm this by checking the generated sequences file in the <AM_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences. The file format will be `<provider>--<API-Name>_v<Version>--<Direction>.xml`